# Tomcat 7 - where do I set 'system properties'?

Tags: apache, session, tomcat, tomcat7

My webapp is having an issue since upgrading to Tomcat 7. My session will go `null` after I login and try to do anything (submitting a request). I've read that setting the following may help:

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.http.ServerCookie.FWD_SLASH_IS_SEPARATOR=false
```

Does anyone know where to set this? Should this be set in `web.xml`, `context.xml` or somewhere else?

The other thing I want to check is the following:

```
org.apache.catalina.STRICT_SERVLET_COMPLIANCE
```

Comment: I read the following, http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/systemprops.html and i did not see any information on where to set this. I just need to know how to correctly set that FWD_SLASH_IS_SEPARATOR to false.

Comment: Also, we're running on a windows environment.

Comment: @Michael - Where in RUNNING.txt does it show WHERE to set FWD_SLASH_IS_SEPARATOR? Are you referring to how it shows you how to set variables (in windows) to setenv.bat?

Comment: we made our change in the <context> of SERVER.XML, not in setenv.bat, is one way more accepted than the other? Thanks.

Comment: @Michael-O instead of answering to question you are playing.

Answer (score 45):

You can set any of the system properties in

```
apache-tomcat-7.0.33\conf\catalina.properties
```

file. Adding your entry in this file should resolve your problem.

E.g.

```
environment=local
```

Answer (score 19):

You can set system properties in Tomcat by creating a `setenv.sh` file in /bin directory.
I did the following to set the system properties.

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Dmyprojectvar.subname=value -Danothervariable=value -Danother.variable=value"
```

Remember:

There is no space between the `export JAVA_OPTS` and `=`. Also: the symbol `&` is different, use `.`.

Now, run your `catalina.sh` to start tomcat.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't set **secret** values (e.g. truststore passwords) that way without revealing them to anyone who can log on and run 'ps' or read /proc/*/cmdline.  Defining them in catalina.properties avoids that leakage.This is one reason why using custom system properties to configure servlet code is a _bad idea_.   Use context parameters instead.

Comment: In addition to the caveat raised by @MarkWood, this technique will only work when Tomcat is launched using the startup scripts. If you use another facility to launch Tomcat (e.g. as a Microsoft Windows "Service"), scripts such as `bin/setenv.sh|bat` are ignored. Using `catalina.properties` ensures that the system properties are set regardless of the way Tomcat is launched.

Comment: instead of JAVA_OPTS - create a new system property and then include it , that way you don't mess up systems existing properties - ex i configured log path this way -   export  "LOG_CONFIG= -DMY_LOG=root/users/myUser/data/logs"

Answer (score 5):

You can set these system properties in command line that starts Tomcat. For example, you can have file `setenv.bat` (on `setenv.sh` if you are on linux) in Tomcats `bin` folder with following content:

```
set "CATALINA_OPTS=%CATALINA_OPTS% -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -Dorg.apache.catalina.STRICT_SERVLET_COMPLIANCE=true -Duser.timezone=GMT -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"
```

This file is preferred way of setting properties for Tomcat.

Now, `FWD_SLASH_IS_SEPARATOR` is by default set to `false`. If you set `STRICT_SERVLET_COMPLIANCE` to `true`, the value of `FWD_SLASH_IS_SEPARATOR` will be also set to `true` (and values of some other properties). However, you can set it explicitly to `false`, e.g. using the following in your `setenv` file is fine:

```
-Dorg.apache.catalina.STRICT_SERVLET_COMPLIANCE=true
-Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.http.ServerCookie.FWD_SLASH_IS_SEPARATOR=false
```

This is also what I suggest when someone sets `STRICT_SERVLET_COMPLIANCE` to `true`, to always disable the `FWD_SLASH_IS_SEPARATOR`. Otherwise, the cookie Path value will be sent quoted (e.g. `"\"`) and all browsers as of today, except Opera, do not recognize this and would e.g. fail to track the session.

Answer (score 3):

**THE SOLUTION:**

```
sessionCookiePathUsesTrailingSlash="false"
```

We actually figured out how to solve this. It was a Tomcat 7 setting we needed to set. We placed it in `server.xml`, under the tag as follows:

```
<Context path="/test" reloadable="true" docBase="c:\webapp\test" 
workDir="c:\webapp\test" sessionCookiePathUsesTrailingSlash="false"/>
```

When we were debugging the problem and looking at the cookies path we noticed it was putting a `\` backslash after the webapp name, so for our test webapp it was setting the path to `/test/` instead of `/test`. This caused a bunch of problems.

Has anyone else had to deal with this setting in Tomcat 7? Or have a similar problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to set variables for a server running in eclipse:

1. Select Run > Run Configurations
2. Make sure your server is selected
3. Select Environment Tab
4. Click 'New' to add a new variable