# Dorg.apache.el.parser.COERCE_TO_ZERO in Apache Tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

Where can I find this parameter `Dorg.apache.el.parser.COERCE_TO_ZERO` in an Apache Tomcat 7 installation ?
 I looked at `apache-tomcat-7.0.33\conf\catalina.properties` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9520987/tomcat-7-where-do-i-set-system-properties) on stackoverflow, but didn't find it.

Comment: The parameter is `org.apache.el.parser.COERCE_TO_ZERO`, the D comes from how you specify it on the command line as `-D<yourPropertyNameHere>`. Try adding it without the D to your property file.

Answer (score 1):

It is a system property.
If you want it as apache configuration, drop the -D prefix which is for java command line.

If it is not in your configuration file, you may just as well add it as described [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/systemprops.html).

> **org.apache.el.parser. COERCE_TO_ZERO**
>    - If true, when coercing expressions to numbers "" and null will be coerced to zero as required by the specification.

If not specified, the default value of true will be used.