# Where can i find the org.apache.catalina.connector.RECYCLE_FACADES system property of tomcat and how to change it's value?

Tags: tomcat

Where can i find the "org.apache.catalina.connector.RECYCLE_FACADES" 
system property of tomcat and how to change it's value?

Answer (score 1):

The property `org.apache.catalina.connector.RECYCLE_FACADES` is not defined in the out of the box script/config files (it's `false` by default see https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/systemprops.html#Security)

There's a few ways to add a system property definition to the tomcat start-up parameters (see also [Tomcat 7 - where do I set 'system properties'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9520987/tomcat-7-where-do-i-set-system-properties)).

I'd recommend the `setenv.bat|sh` approach - create the file in `TOMCAT_HOME/bin` if not there already.

Example `setenv.bat`:

```
@echo off
set "CATALINA_OPTS=%CATALINA_OPTS% -Dorg.apache.catalina.connector.RECYCLE_FACADES=true"
```

Example `setenv.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Dorg.apache.catalina.connector.RECYCLE_FACADES=true"
```