# Externalizing configuration for a Spring boot war file in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, gradle, spring-boot

I have a Spring boot web application  deployed to tomcat's webapps directory. I also have the profile based `application-<profile>.properties` file.  How to make the profile to be set automatically for dev,staging and prod environments. How to achieve this using Tomcat and how to make it to be chosen within the application itself without tomcat . It would be better if I am not setting the active profile in application.properties by default .

Answer (score 1):

Spring Boot allows you to externalize your configuration so you can work with the same application code in different environments. You can use properties files, YAML files, environment variables and command-line arguments to externalize configuration.

Spring Boot uses a very particular PropertySource order that is designed to allow sensible overriding of values. Properties are considered in the following order:

- Java System properties (System.getProperties()).
- OS environment variables.

This can be achieved using [system environment property](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config):

1. Add the below entry in environment variable in system.

   **spring.profiles.active = dev**
2. Make sure that you have application-dev.properties in your boot project.

Comment: Is there any other way than setting the environment variable in System

Comment: You can try using JNDI variable java:comp/env/spring.application.json or try the java system properties[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9520987/tomcat-7-where-do-i-set-system-properties]